# how is the time complexity of dict.clear() is O(1) in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity, python-internals

According to https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt, time complexity of dict.clear() is O(1).

As far as I know, dict.clear() is not same as assigning dict = {}, as dict.clear() make changes to same dict, while dict = {} create a new dict.

Now if dict.clear() is clearing the same dict object, then how it can complete it in O(1).

Comment: maybe by trashing the internal data structure and leave garbage collector do the dirty non O(1) work. It's NOT looping through elements and delete one by one.

Comment: The implemention for `PyDict_Clear` can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1636).

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
Py_CLEAR(oldvalues[i]);` that doesn't look like `O(1)` to me... seems that I was wrong

Comment: interestingly, complexity of clear isn't discussed here https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 5):

Some rationale for why it is being claimed to be O(1):

The `clear()` method is actually just assigning the internal dictionary structures to new empty values (as can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1636)). The seemingly O(n) part is a result of decrementing reference counts, and other GC-related stuff. But this is purely a function of the GC approach that CPython uses (i.e. reference counting); you can envision different approaches that wouldn't require explicit cleanup like this, or where the cleanup would happen much later (or even be amortized away). Since ideally the time complexity of `clear()` shouldn't depend on the underlying GC approach, all GC-related parts are omitted, making it "O(1)". IMO this is mostly a definitional argument than anything else, but this is at least some justification.

Answer (score 3):

I first thought that `dict.clear` just performed some reference decrease to let the garbage collector do the dirty non-O(1) work, but looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1636) (thanks timgeb for providing the link) it doesn't seem to be that:

```
   oldvalues = mp->ma_values;
    if (oldvalues == empty_values)
        return;
    /* Empty the dict... */
    dictkeys_incref(Py_EMPTY_KEYS);
    mp->ma_keys = Py_EMPTY_KEYS;
    mp->ma_values = empty_values;
    mp->ma_used = 0;
    mp->ma_version_tag = DICT_NEXT_VERSION();
    /* ...then clear the keys and values */
    if (oldvalues != NULL) {
        n = oldkeys->dk_nentries;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            Py_CLEAR(oldvalues[i]);
```

What I see is that if the dictionary had values, then a loop is performed to decrease references those values and set the pointers to `NULL`. So seems to be `O(n)` not `O(1)` since it depends on the number of the values.

When you assign to a new dict like this `d = {}`, this is `O(1)`, but the garbage collector must delete the old object when not referenced anymore. That may not be right when assigning, but that will happen, unless python quits abruptly.